# propagate OpenTracing TraceIds from publisher to consumer using MassTransit.RabbitMQ

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit, opentracing

Using MassTransit.RabbitMQ v5.3.2 and OpenTracing.Contrib.NetCore v0.5.0.

I'm able publish and consume events to RabbitMQ using MassTransit and I've got OpenTracing working with Jaeger, but I haven't managed to get my OpenTracing TraceIds propogated from my message publisher to my message consumer - The publisher and consumer traces have different TraceIds.

I've configured MassTransit with the following filter:

```
cfg.UseDiagnosticsActivity(new DiagnosticListener("test"));
```

I'm not actually sure what the listener name should be, hence "test". The [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/monitoring/diagnostic-source.html) doesn't have an example for OpenTracing. Anyways, this adds a 'Publishing Message' span to the active trace on the publish side, and automatically sets up a 'Consuming Message' trace on the consumer side; however they're separate traces. How would I go about consolidating this into a single trace?

I could set a TraceId header using:

```
cfg.ConfigureSend(configurator => configurator.UseExecute(context => context.Headers.Set("TraceId", GlobalTracer.Instance.ActiveSpan.Context.TraceId)))
```

but then how would I configure my message consumer so that this is the root TraceId? Interested to see how I might do this, or if there's a different approach...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone is interested; I ended up solving this by creating some publish and consume MassTransit middleware to do the trace propagation via trace injection and extraction respectively.

I've put the solution up on GitHub - https://github.com/yesmarket/MassTransit.OpenTracing

Still interested to hear if there's a better way of doing this...